# What's the difference between [String] vs. [(String)]?

Tags: swift

What's the difference between [String] and [(String)] in Swift?
I get them using `let arr1 : [String]` and `let arr2 = [String]()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[String] is an array of strings, while [(String)] is an array of tuples which contain 1 string.

```
let arr1 = [("test")]
arr1[0].0 // contains "test"

let arr2 = ["test"]
arr2[0] // contains "test"
```

A more useful array of tuples might be something like:

```
let arr1: [(id: Int, name: String)] = [(12, "Fred"), (43, "Bob")]
arr1[0].name // contains "Fred"
```

Comment: This implies `[(String)]` and `[String]` are somehow different, but they aren’t (or shouldn’t be).  Note, `arr1[0]` and `arr2[0].0` also both return “test”.

Comment: Is it possible that swift can coerce a tuple of 1 item into just that item? I would be interested to look at the behavior of this a little closer.

Comment: They should be completely interchangeable: `let a: [(Int)] = [1,(2)];let b: [Int] = a;let c: [(Int)] = b`

Comment: Every single type is implemented as a tuple containing only one value, Airspeed Velocity s answer is definitely correct

Answer (score 9):

There should be no difference – this is a glitch somewhere in Xcode or Swift if you see `[(String)]`.  In theory, all variables are single element tuples – this is why every variable has a `.0` property:

```
let s = "hello"
print(s.0)
```

but in practice this ought to get normalized out so that you never see `(OneThing)`, only ever `OneThing`.

Comment: This is a really interesting Swift fact and should probably be marked as the answer.