# What is the difference between '(String)' and 'String' in a Swift error message

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors

1. I wrote a function that takes a non-optional String as a parameter.
2. I declared a variable property of type String, which is also not an optional.
3. When I try to call my function with this property as an argument, I get the following error.

> Cannot invoke 'localesForCountryCode' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Notice that the error lists the type as `'(String)'` not `'String'`.  **What do  the parens signify?** I *thought* they meant that the type was optional, but nothing is declared as an optional anywhere.

**My Function (An extension of NSLocale):**

```
func localesForCountryCode(countryCode: String) -> [NSLocale] {
    let localeIdentifiers = localeIdentifiersForCountryCode(countryCode)
    var locales = [NSLocale]()
    for localeIdentifier in localeIdentifiers {
        let localeForIdentifier = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: localeIdentifier)
        locales.append(localeForIdentifier)
    }
    return locales
}
```

**Code That Calls My Function**

```
let currentCountryCode = "US"
var localesForCurrentCountry = [NSLocale]()

func updateWithNewLocation(newLocation: CLLocation) {
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks.first as! CLPlacemark
            self.currentCountry = placemark.country
            self.localesForCurrentCountry = NSLocale.localesForCountryCode(self.currentCountryCode)   
        }
    })
}
```

---

### Update 1

When I move my function code from the NSLocale extension to the view controller from which I am calling the function, the error goes away. **Any ideas why this may be the case?** Absolutely no changes to the function were made.

### Update 2

I continue to run into this problem.  The following is another example. Again, it seems to happen only when a function is called as a class method.
[image]

Comment: can you show use the code please?

Comment: The parens just indicate the types and list of parameters for the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235069

Comment: rintaro this is a different question.

Comment: I think you may have to mac the `func` a `class func` since you refer to it via `NSLocale.`!

Answer (score 3):

I was rereading your question and realized that your question is not really your question. Your problem has nothing to do with parentheses (see below about why). You're just calling the wrong method. `NSDateComponentsFormatter` is a class. `stringFromTimeInterval()` is an instance method. You have to crate an actual date formatter to work with. If you want a default one, you can do this:

```
return NSDateComponentsFormatter().stringFromTimeInterval(unwrappedTimespan)
```

Note the extra set of parentheses. Your probably don't want the default one, though. You probably want to configure one. See [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) for an introduction to that topic. Note that date formatters can be pretty expensive to create, so you usually want to reuse them.

You're doing the same thing with `localesForCountryCode`. This is an instance method, not a class method. You have to create an `NSLocale` first.

This does open up an interesting topic, though. Why does `NSDateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval()` act like a function that you're just passing the wrong arguments to? Why doesn't it say "hey, you're calling a class method?" It's because it *is* a function that you're just passing the wrong arguments to.

Every method is really just a curried function that takes the target object as the first parameter. See Ole Begemann's quick intro to the topic: [Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

---

*Some more on your explicit question about parentheses:*

As others have noted, a `(String)` is a one-tuple of `String`. The important point is that in Swift, any type is trivially convertible to a one-tuple of that type, so the extra parentheses here are unimportant. There is no meaningful distinction between `String` and `(String)` in Swift.

All Swift functions technically take one value and return one value. So one can correctly think of:

```
func f(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int
```

as a function that takes a tuple `(Int,y:Int)` and returns an `Int` (or possibly `(Int)`; I believe Swift actually does the former, though). This is subtly connected to how currying works in Swift. In a simpler case:

```
func f(x: Int)
```

This is a function that technically takes `(Int)` and returns `()`. That's why sometimes you will see `(Type)` show up in error messages. But it is not a meaningful distinction.

Answer (score 0):

`String` - it's simple [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) type.
But `(String)` - it's a compound type called [`Tuple`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html).
That means you passing to you function `Tuple`, not `String`.

---

> A compound type is a type without a name, defined in the Swift language itself. There are two compound types: function types and tuple types. A compound type may contain named types and other compound types. For instance, the tuple type (Int, (Int, Int)) contains two elements: The first is the named type Int, and the second is another compound type (Int, Int).

Comment: But the documentation states also: *If there is only one element inside the parentheses, the type is simply the type of that element. For example, the type of `(Int)` is `Int`, not `(Int)`.*

Comment: @MartinR, yeah, now i see that. But i posted the answer before any sample code in question ;) Anyway, thanx for remark.

Answer (score 0):

In general the error message says `(String)` because that is the tuple / list of parameters. If you method would expect a `String` and afterwards an `Int` an error message might mention `(String, paramName: Int)`

So basically so far everything looks fine. You need to show us the code for us to be able to fix your exact problem. Because `String` and `(String)` normally should match in the given scenario.

Consider the following example:

```
func k (a:String, b:Int) {}
k(12, b:"123")
```

which will cause the error

> Cannot invoke 'k' with an argument list of type (Int, b:String)

While

```
k("12", b:123)
```

does what you would expect.